# Gmail sending to phantom targets

Tags: gmail

When I send out an email to several different groups, it always sends to a  non-existent 'john.smith@case.edu'.  There was someone by this name in my contact list at one time, but was long ago deleted.  The auto-complete cannot find this name; I have also searched manually and can't find it.  What can be causing this?  How can I get rid of it?

Also, I incorrectly typed in someone's email as 'john@@something.com'.  When I got an error I fixed the email.  But Gmail is still sending it with the `@@`.  I've checked and it is corrected. How can I get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Contacts email addresses edits are not propagated to groups. You should edit both, the email addresses in the contact record and the related groups.

Comment: Hi Ruben,  I checked the names in the groups and apparently my edit of the main contact did go through to the group.  In fact, I'm thinking that the groups do not contain separate records, but only pointers to their members.  I'm also completely at a loss about not being able to find a contact that gmail keeps sending mail to.